# Maven-bundle-plugin - Export without version

Tags: maven, bundle, manifest, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm using the "maven-bundle-plugin" to generate the MANIFEST.MF actomaticaly. Now I need to export a bundle without version.

I'm  introducing this configuration:

```
<Export-Package>
  org.name.package 
</Export-Package>
```

But the plugin introduce directly the version of the bundle:

```
Export-Package: org.name.package;version="0.0.1"
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bundle version and exported package version are two different things. In your case you are talking about package version.

Just set `<version>2.1.0</version>` to the maven-bundle-plugin. This should export all packages without version but I think it is bug or something.